# configure jetty 9.3.0 embedded (programmatically) with caching

Tags: java, caching, jetty

I can't seem to get my jetty to work with caching.
I have a jetty server that will display html only.
I have JavaScripts in there and a lot of images which I don't want to load every time. For example my application needs to switch in 10 seconds between 3 pages. Loading jQuery three times is time consuming and loading the logo picture and all that takes even longer. That's why I want to enable Caching.

This is what I got:

```
server = new Server(); //new Jetty Server
//setting up a ssl connection
try
{
    SslContextFactory cf = new SslContextFactory();
    cf.setKeyStorePath(keystore);
    cf.setKeyStorePassword("password");
    
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
    config.setSecureScheme("https");
    config.setSecurePort(8443);
    
    HttpConfiguration sslConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration(config);
    sslConfiguration.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
    
    httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server);
    httpConnector.addConnectionFactory(new HttpConnectionFactory(config));
    httpConnector.setPort(suggestHttpPort());
    httpConnector.setName("unsecured");
    sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server, 
            new SslConnectionFactory(cf, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.toString()), 
            new HttpConnectionFactory(sslConfiguration));
    sslConnector.setPort(suggestHttpSSLPort());
    sslConnector.setName("secured");
    
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { httpConnector, sslConnector });  
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.error("setting up Jetty failed", e);
}
// This is where i want to enable caching, at least that is what i have figuged out so far but its not working
DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(defaultServlet);
holder.setInitParameter("cacheControl", "max-age=120, public");
ServletContextHandler bb = new ServletContextHandler();
bb.addServlet(holder, "/");
server.setHandler(bb);
server.start();
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to enable caching for everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ServletHolder` directly like that against a started Servlet, let the `ServletHolder` create and init the class reference instead.

You'll want a `ServletContextHandler` and a defined Base Resource that the `DefaultServlet` can utilize as well (this should be a URI pointing to the root of your static file content)

Example:

```java
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));

ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
holderPwd.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
holderPwd.setInitParameter("cacheControl", "max-age=3600,public");
context.addServlet(holderPwd,"/");
server.setHandler(context);
```

Comment: I'll give that a try just a quick follow up question: If I have additional Handler that are loaded later can I add them to the server just with server.addHandler(handler) or do I have to add them to the ServletContextHandler?

Comment: I got it working. After server.start() i had to additionally start the ServletContextHandler too with context.start(). THX

Comment: @voodoo if you had to manually start the `ServletContextHandler` then something is seriously wrong and that would be a bad bug.  The fact that you call `server.setHandler(context)` would add that handler to the `ContainerLifeCycle` of the server forcing the `ServletContextHandler` to start before the server.